# Create additional rows in excel

Tags: excel

How can I add new rows from:-

```
Column A        Column B         Column C
11               Size              S
11               Color             Yellow
11               Type              Q
22               Size              M
22               Color             Blue
22               Type              W
33               Size              L
33               Color             Brown
33               Type              R
```

to this in excel:-

```
Column A        Column B         Column C
11               Size              S
11               Color             Yellow
11               Type              Q
11               Model             T1
11               Grade             1
11               LotNo             Z10
22               Size              M
22               Color             Blue
22               Type              W
22               Model             T2
22               Grade             1
22               LotNo             M10
33               Size              L
33               Color             Brown
33               Type              R
33               Model             T3
33               Grade             2
33               LotNo             C10
```

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Highlight 3 rows, right click, select Insert, repeat. Type new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean doing this in VBA (since it's tagged `macros` and this is a programming Q&A site), you can insert and populate a row with code like:

```
Range("A3").EntireRow.Insert
Range("A3").Formula = "=11"
Range("B3").Value = "Hello"
```

Everything else is just figuring out a loop which will do the whole thing. The code below will expand the rows as you desire (by adding `Model`, `Grade` and `LotNo` rows after each `Type` row). The actual values of those items are left as `??` since it's not clear how to calculate them from the other data.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = 1
    While Range("B" & Row).Value <> ""
        Row = Row + 1
    Wend
    While Row <> 1
        If Range("B" & (Row - 1)).Value = "Type" Then
            Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
            Range("A" & Row).Formula = Range("A" & (Row - 1)).Formula
            Range("B" & Row).Value = "LotNo"
            Range("C" & Row).Value = "??"

            Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
            Range("A" & Row).Formula = Range("A" & (Row - 1)).Formula
            Range("B" & Row).Value = "Grade"
            Range("C" & Row).Value = "??"

            Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
            Range("A" & Row).Formula = Range("A" & (Row - 1)).Formula
            Range("B" & Row).Value = "Model"
            Range("C" & Row).Value = "??"

        End If
        Row = Row - 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I hv hundreds of such items to be added. This will save me a lot.